# ASP.NET Masterpage

Tags: asp.net

May I know is it able for one ASP file to access 2 different Masterpage depending on user's selection? Is like a theme feature. It will actually fetch the selection data from database based on the user's latest selection and the ASP page that the user is trying to access will display together with the last selected theme (Masterpage).

Example:

Theme - Green (Green.masterpage) and Blue (Blue.masterpage)
User selected Green theme and it was saved to the database
User access home.asp and it will display together with Green theme (Green.masterpage)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Or look into [ASP.Net Themes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use any masterpage based on your condition, but make sure you do it in Page_PreInit event of your content page

```
void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (condition....)
MasterPageFile = "~/Green.master";
}
if (condition....)
MasterPageFile = "~/Blue.master";
}

 }
```